# how i can display the image path which i'm getting from the back end while editing the camp

Tags: node.js, angular, file

**i want to display the file path as input value when working on editing**

*the reason is that when i click on edit button all the others values (data) of camp is put into the input fields but the url of camp is not placing in the input filed*

**This is my camp.ts file**

```
  form  = new FormGroup({
    title:new FormControl('',),
    images: new FormControl(''),
    location: new FormControl(''),
    price: new FormControl(''),
    description: new FormControl('')
 
    })
   public uploadFile(event: Event): void {
   const input = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    if (!input.files?.length) {
     return;
   }
   const file = input.files[0];
   this.form.patchValue({
    images: file
   });
   this.form.get('images');
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.id = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
   this.getData();
  }
  get f(){
   return this.form.controls;
  }
  getData(){
    this.campgroundService.getDataById(this.id).subscribe(res => {
    this.data = res; 
    this.campground = this.data;
    this.form =  new FormGroup({
    title: new FormControl(this.campground.title, Validators.required),
    images: new FormControl(this.campground.images[0].url , Validators.required),
    location: new FormControl(this.campground.location, Validators.required),
    price: new FormControl(this.campground.price, Validators.required),
    description: new FormControl(this.campground.description, Validators.required)
    });
    console.log('Fetching Form Values from backend',this.form.value);
    console.log('file data = ', this.campground.images[0].url);
    });
   }
```

**This is my camp.html file**

```
<div class="form-group" >
    <label for="title"> Enter Title </label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="title" placeholder="Enter Title" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':submitted && f.title.errors}" class="form-control">
    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.title.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
        <div *ngIf="f.title.errors.required">
            Title Is Required!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Image Input -->
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="image"> Selcet Image </label>
    <input type="file" name="images" id="image" (change)="uploadFile($event)" class="form-control" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add *formControlName="images"* to the second input:

```
    <input
       class="form-control"
       formControlName="images"
       type="file"
       name="images"
       id="image"
       (change)="uploadFile($event)" 
       accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg"
    >
```

By the way, maybe it would be better if you do the form initialization at the beginning of your code, already with validators.
Then, when yo get the data response, you only have to update the values of the fields and do not re-create the form-controls for them.

Something like that:

```
form  = new FormGroup({
    title:new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    images: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    location: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    price: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    description: new FormControl('', Validators.required) 
    })

...

getData(){
    this.campgroundService.getDataById(this.id)
    .subscribe(
       res => {
          this.data = res; 
          this.campground = this.data;
          this.form.patchValue({
             title: this.campground.title,
             images: this.campground.images[0].url,
             location: this.campground.location,
             price: this.campground.price,
             description: this.campground.description,
          });
 
    console.log('Fetching Form Values from backend',this.form.value);
    console.log('file data = ', this.campground.images[0].url);
    });
   }
```

Comment: now its giving me that error  == > ERROR DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.

Comment: In order to better help, you should show the console log of 'res' of your ".subscribe(res". About the new error, try to delete from the html this 'accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" '. I don't really know what you are trying to save in that field...

Comment: i just want to place the url which i'm getting from the back end into the input